# Return collection from php script to my android app

Tags: java, php, android, mongodb, parsing

I am wondering if there is a way to return a mongo collection from php script to java. Lets say that i am connecting to url in my Android application like this:

```
URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "db.php");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

where db.php is this:

```
$db = new Mongo('mongodb://.../test');
$c_things = $db->things;
```

where `$c_things` is the collection.

Could i retrieve/parse `$c_things` in my app as `MongoCollection<Document> format`? If there is a tutorial out there is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use bson_encode on the php side to generate a BSON string and return that. And then on the Java side user he mongo DB BSON decode function to turn it back into a collection.

Comment: This sounds about wright.. I will try it tommorow and give feedback :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to do that is with JSONArray try return that from Server and use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to consuming the service properly.